# Android приложение перестало запускатся

Tags: android

Я не понимаю, у меня есть Fragment я в него перенес код из Activity, почему при нажатии приложение крашится. И можете подсказать как что-то понимать в логах. Я вроде бы смотрю слова знакомые а из-за чего ошибка выскакивает не пойму.

Java

```
public class ItemFiveFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout expandableLayout1;
    private com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout expandableLayout2;
    private com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout expandableLayout3;
    private com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout expandableLayout4;

    public static ItemFiveFragment newInstance()
    {
        return new ItemFiveFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_setting, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        expandableLayout1 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout1);
        expandableLayout1.toggle(); // toggle expand and collapse

        expandableLayout2 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout2);
        expandableLayout2.toggle(); // toggle expand and collapse

        expandableLayout3 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout3);
        expandableLayout3.toggle(); // toggle expand and collapse

        expandableLayout4 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout4);
        expandableLayout4.toggle(); // toggle expand and collapse
    }
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
    }

}
```

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/expandableButton1_frag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ba1f04"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
        android:onClick="expandableButton1_frag"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Expandable Layout Example"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandableLayout1_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expandableButton1_frag"
        android:background="#90ba1f04"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:ael_duration="400"
        app:ael_expanded="false"
        app:ael_interpolator="bounce"
        app:ael_orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Expandable Layout provides an easy way to create a view called header with an expandable view. Views are external layout to allow a maximum of customization." />
    </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/expandableButton2_frag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expandableLayout1_frag"
        android:background="#b77803"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
        android:onClick="expandableButton2_frag"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Expandable Views Tutorial"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandableLayout2_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expandableButton2_frag"
        android:background="#90b77803"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:ael_duration="400"
        app:ael_expanded="false"
        app:ael_interpolator="bounce"
        app:ael_orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Android library for creating an expandable and collapsible to full screen view inside a viewgroup composition. Expandable Layout provides an easy way to create a view called header with an expandable view. Views are external layout to allow a maximum of customization." />
    </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/expandableButton3_frag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expandableLayout2_frag"
        android:background="#10a106"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
        android:onClick="expandableButton3_frag"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Expand/Collapse Android Widgets"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandableLayout3_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expandableButton3_frag"
        android:background="#9010a106"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:ael_duration="400"
        app:ael_expanded="false"
        app:ael_interpolator="bounce"
        app:ael_orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="An android library that brings the expandable and collapsible layouts or views or widgets with various animation effect and material design color. You can include optional contents and use everywhere according to your demand.
An android library that brings the expandable and collapsible layouts or views or widgets with various animation effect and material design color. You can include optional contents and use everywhere according to your demand" />
    </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/expandableButton4_frag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expandableLayout3_frag"
        android:background="#066da1"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
        android:onClick="expandableButton4_frag"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Expand/Collapse Android Example"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandableLayout4_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expandableButton4_frag"
        android:background="#90066da1"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:ael_duration="400"
        app:ael_expanded="false"
        app:ael_interpolator="bounce"
        app:ael_orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Implements the expand and collapse by sliding logic for a top or a bottom view in a two children view  or layout or any widgets composition.
             Implements the expand and collapse by sliding logic for a top or a bottom view in a two children view  or layout or any widgets composition." />
    </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Скриншот из логов 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В приведённом коже ошибок не видно. Судя по логам ошибка скорее там, где вы фрагмент отображаете.

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout1)` а в разметке `id="@+id/expandableLayout1_frag"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я искренне извиняюсь, я перепутал скриншот логов, исправил его, вы могли бы объяснить на какую строку смотреть что бы понять что приводит к ошибке.

Comment: Ищите то, чего нет)

Comment: @Karpuha, вы опечатались (точнее невнимательно переносили код из активити во фрагмент). У вас в разметке id типа `expandableLayout4_frag`, а ищите вы `expandableLayout4`. Вот и выходит у вас NPE.

Comment: Оно крашится на строке 42. Укажите пожалуйста эту строку